# Magento DB Collection generate error on UNION

Tags: magento-1.7, collection

I've try to resolve this issue many hours but end up with no luck.

Here is the senario:

I have a store locator and have 2 types of dealers. Master and General. I need to list Master dealer first  and General Dealers 2nd. Best solution is to use UNION in collection

```
        $cloneSelect = clone( $collection1->getSelect() );
        $collection1->getSelect()->reset()->union(
            array(
                 "( ". $cloneSelect ." )",
                 "( ". $collection2->getSelect() ." )",
             ) );
```

When I view $collection->getSelect()->__toString() this generate ( $collection1 ) UNION  ( $collectio2 )

but when I apply $collection1->getSize() or any method it generate following error.

> No table has been specified for the FROM clause

I know it generate this error becouse $collection need to have from clause, If that's the case dose anyone have IDEA how to do union and get collection

Thanks

Comment: Show the whole SQL please.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can resolve it by sorting results?  Like `order by if(master_condition, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
$select = $collection1->getSelect()->union($collection2->getSelect());
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem when using `union` in the **Widget_Grid** block "_prepareCollection()" method, that in the process calls the getSize() method you mentioned.

I solved it by using a third auxiliary collection (of which I only selected one key field), and then *`join`ing* it with my "united" collections on that same key.